# Include files from other folder outside of angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, environments

In angular-cli.json , I am trying to set some environments file which won't be a part of the project . The root is set to src which I want to keep intact but in environments config I want something like this to work

```
"environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts",
        "stage":"environments/environment.stage.ts",
        "cust1-dev": 
"../CustomerConfiguration/Cust/UI/src/environments/environment.ts",     
}
```

Is this possible ? Currently This doesnt work.

Comment: try using path.resolve from path module

Comment: Any reason you need to do this?

Comment: There is a different folder structure and repo for each of the customers @WilliamHampshire. I wanted to use that instead of copying it within the enviroments folder.